# Remove greasy material from wooden frame

Tags: kitchens, wooden-furniture

There is a wooden frame in my kitchen and due to cooking/heating the wooden frame right above my burner is become greasy.

how i remove that greasy material from wooden frame, as i tried to remove it from water with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most household degreasers work just fine.  Krud Kutter works great, Lysol lemon degreaser also works well.paint thinner even works well as a degreaser

Comment: Is it all good on wood?

Comment: Odds are if this is a couple years in the making (I know mine gets gross before I do anything) you are going to have to spray and let it penetrate for a little while, and it will likely take a few coats.

Comment: i spray this....and leave it for half a day, then wiped it . I do this step for two times and it remove grease...thanks